# While converting json to tsv( "\t" is my delimineter) there are new line character in values, How do i get rid of them

Tags: python

## Code

```
import json
import csv

with open('output.tsv', 'w') as output_file, open('data.json') as data_file:    
    j = json.load(data_file)
    dw = csv.DictWriter(output_file, sorted(j[0].keys()), delimiter='\t')
    dw.writeheader()
    dw.writerows(j)
```

## Data

```
[{"x" : "jkafadsnkas", "y" : "sa,nn\n"},{"x" : "jkaf\nadsnkas", "y" : "sa,nn\n"}]
```

## Output

```
x   y

jkafadsnkas "sa,nn
"

"jkaf
adsnkas"    "sa,nn
"
```

## Wanted Output

```
x   y


"jkafadsnkas    "sa,nn"

"jkafadsnkas"   "sa,nn"
```

I want that new line character must be stripped of from the data while writing in the tsv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the data json I see you have `\n` you should strip it first you can do that by

```
data = {k:data[k].strip() for k in data}
```

than you can feed this into the csvWriter do it after you load the json

Comment: i have to do this for all of the keys in my json and i have to convert a large file say 7gb so wont it be inefficient

Comment: what happens if i have an nested json file, gives me error 'dict' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: you need to strip the value only I don't think it is that inefficient try streaming the data with a buffer (don't read it all at once except if you have 8GB of ram) for nested json I need more example

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want, I modify the code as follows:

```
import json
import csv

with open('output.tsv', 'w') as output_file, open('data.json') as data_file:
    j = json.load(data_file)
    j = [{k: v.replace('\n', '') for k, v in jj.items()} for jj in j]
    dw = csv.DictWriter(output_file, sorted(j[0].keys()), delimiter='\t')
    dw.writeheader()
    dw.writerows(j)
```